# Guide to crawling sharepoint from a third party app

Tags: crawl

Sometimes from Sharepoint you want access to the sharepoint Lists Items+attachents with Permissions, Files with Permissions, etc.

Are there any programs that can copy all the files from sharepoint to file system super fast?

I have a simpler program that just makes SOAP web service calls and it's ok but kinda slow. I'm wondering if anyone already has something written maybe in powershell that can copy a sharepoint site to a folder mega fast (multiple threads).